# How to use a StreamSubscription with Flutter Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, riverpod

I'm using FlutterReactiveBle to "listen" and stream my commands and to send a custom characteristic. So, I decided to create a StateProvider in Riverpod to populate a list of strings with the data received in my characteristic (Bluetooth) listener.

```dart
final bluetoothServiceProvider = Provider<BluetoothService>((ref) {
  return BluetoothService();
});

final streamDataProvider = StateProvider<List<String>>((ref) {
  return [];
});

final streamSubscriptionProvider = StateProvider.family<void, bool>((ref, onOff) {
  final characteristicTX = QualifiedCharacteristic(
    serviceId: SERVICE_UUID,
    characteristicId: CHARACTERISTIC_TX_UUID,
    deviceId: "60:A4:23:C9:10:10",
  );
  final socket = ref
      .read(bluetoothServiceProvider)
      .flutterReactiveBle
      .subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristicTX)
      .listen((event) {
    ref.read(streamDataProvider.notifier).state = [
      ...ref.read(streamDataProvider.notifier).state,
      "${DateTime.now()} - ${utf8.decode(event)}",
    ];
  });

  if (onOff) {
    print("RESUME");
    socket.resume();
    print(socket.isPaused);
  } else {
    print("CANCEL");
    socket.cancel();
    print(socket.isPaused);
  }
});
```

Here is my HomeView where I can send commands and display the data from `streamDataProvider` in my ListView.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("APP")),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      const SizedBox(height: 20),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              ref.read(streamSubscriptionProvider(true));
            },
            child: const Text("Turn on stream"),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              ref.read(streamSubscriptionProvider(false));
            },
            child: const Text("Turn off stream"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 20),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await ref.read(bluetoothServiceProvider).getVersion(mine);
            },
            child: const Text("Send command 'Get version'"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 20),
      Expanded(
        child: Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            itemCount: ref.watch(streamDataProvider).length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Text(
                ref.watch(streamDataProvider)[index],
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 8),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to stop or resume the `streamSubscription` with my buttons. The socket never gets canceled, and I still receive data in my ListView.

Here is the library I use for BLE: [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble#subscribe-to-characteristic).

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Do you have an example how to use streamprovider with a stream from BLE package?
I don't understand how to "Link" them together

Comment: in build(), use .listen on your incoming stream, and use "state = " in your listen handler to update the state for each event.  I believe there are numerous samples of mapping a stream to an AsyncNotifier[Provider]

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` does not have a `==` method that is usable to be a raw family key.  You need to use generated providers, which can work around that, or use something like an `IList<T>` from [fast_immutable_collections](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections).

Comment: This is not really my problem. I can't cancel or resume my riverpod stream

Comment: But the problem is that [3, 4, 5] does not equal [3, 4, 5], so every time you construct a new list from the same values, it is a DIFFERENT list and therefore a DIFFERENT provider.

Comment: Where do you see I'm trying to make a [3.4.5] = [3.4.5] ?

Comment: Oh.. I see there's an entirely differerent problem.  You are creating two separate streams... one for the streamSubscriptionProvider(false) and the other for the streamSubscriptionProvider(true).  Those are two separate providers!